# MySQL server database connection for multiple computers

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have a messenger sort of program that connects with the MySQL server database(xampp 127.0.0.1).
here's my connection string:-

```
String^constring=L"Addr=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=database";
```

The application runs great in my own computer. 
i have installed that application in 3 of my friend's computers, but it fails and says:-

"unable to connect to any of the specified MYSQL host"

and I want to connect them with the same databases without installing mysql or xampp on their computer.what should I do?

please guide step by step

Thank You

Comment: If you have your database running locally on your computer, on a dynamic IP, there's no way for your friends to connect to it from their homes. Bring your DB up on a cloud service or something. Also, read the SO guidelines, this is no place for such questions.

Comment: They will presumably need a slightly different connection string, since the IP address to the MySQL server will not be 127.0.0.1.  Apart from that, try it and see what happens.  You may need to GRANT permissions.  Without knowing your network setup, it's very hard to answer this question.

Comment: how to show you my network setup?

Comment: Are your friends computers in the same room or the other side of the world?  Do you have static IP addresses?  Routers/switches/firewalls etc..?  I'd also post this to either https://serverfault.com/ or https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: sir my friend's computer ar far away from mine.

Comment: My computer is connected with wifi router.

Comment: and i have static ip adress

Comment: It's probably your firewall blocking incoming connections, assuming you have your correct IP address in your friends connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution...

first of all make your xampp server online through portforwarding or virtual server
watch this video to know how to put xampp server online:-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U46Ku2oKCPU

then in the connection string add static public ip instead of local ip address(127.0.0.1)